# Linux Ubuntu 18.04 - Sculpting performance (dyntopo) is terrible in comparison to Windows

Tags: sculpting, performance, linux

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
CPU: i5-6600K
GPU: GTX 970
RAM: 32 GB

Sculpting on objects with more 100k polygons (dyntopo constant detail 50 px) lags blender, especially using Snake Hook brush and dragging freezes Blender.

For comparison - on Win10 I can handle 1.5m polygons with Snake Hook with similar performance.

I have Nvidia 396, Cuda and most likely other Nvidia stuff installed too.
I tried Blender 2.77, 2.79 from archive, from synaptic, on steam and 2.8 as well, all of them have the same terrible performance.

Since I was moving from Win to Ubuntu, I used Win startup.blend file so I have most of in-blender optimizations activated, Cuda, backface culling included.

Is this a normal occurrence and I should stay on Win10 or is there something wrong with my Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

This is not normal. The entire Blender Animation Studio is running Linux, with many machines using NVidia GPUs. All the Open Movies were made on Linux.